# How can I connect to ArcSDE with GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, arcgis-server

I'm running Oracle ArcSDE 9.2 and using GeoTools 8.5, but doing what they say in the GeoTools docs doesn't seem to work.  I have

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put( "dbtype", "arcsde" );
params.put( "server", "164.64.146.42" );
params.put( "port", "5151" );
params.put( "instance", "sde" );
params.put( "user", "sde_admin" );
params.put( "password", "whatever" );

DataStore dataStore;
String typeName;

try
{
    dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
    typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FeatureSource source = dataStore(typeName);
```

But, after dataStore = dataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params), dataStore is always still null, indicating it didn't connect.  I do not get an exception unless I try to use the dataStore object which is null.  And I don't expect it to work because it doesn't ask me for a schema.  When you connect using GeoServer successfully to the same SDE geodatabase, it insists on a schema parameter, which in my case is "envq.nmenv.state.nm.us."  Would I add that onto the server name somewhere?  Or what am I missing for this not to connect?  I am just trying to connect read-only for now, but eventually I want to put data in using GeoTools.

Answer (score 1):

Using the software uDig, which uses the GeoTools library, has answered my question.  When loading from an ArcSDE DataStore via uDig, uDig prompts to know the location of the following jars:
jsde92_sdk.jar
jpe92_sdk.jar
icu4j_3_2.jar
They are not loaded automatically via Maven by adding gt-arcsde to your pom.xml in Eclipse, but are distributed with [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Stable) under the ArcSDE Data Store Extension within the filename [geoserver-2.2.2-arcsde-plugin.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer%20Extensions/2.2.2/geoserver-2.2.2-arcsde-plugin.zip)
Add their location to your CLASSPATH or in Eclipse go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path and Add External JARs... and choose all three.  At that point the above code will work unchanged.